# Why is my programming not looping correctly? (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, if-statement, while-loop

**Desired output:** Hello, I am trying to make a program that does addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division and loops until you press 'e' to exit the loop.

So, I want it to look something like this:

```
A. Addition
B. Subtraction
C. Multiplication
D. Division
E. Exit

Please enter your selection, enter E to end: 
//let's say they enter a, and want to add 5 plus 5

Enter your first number: 
Enter your second number:

5 + 5 = 10.0

Please enter your selection, enter E to end:
//This looping part is what I want to happen! But my program just ends, and I'm not 
sure how to fix it
```

**Issue:** My problem is that once you enter what operation you want, it only does the arithmetic once and then it displays my exit message and ends, but that is only supposed to happen when the user enters 'e' but the rest works, I think!

**Here is my code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator_Loop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char selection;
    char choice = 'E';
    double num_1;
    double num_2;
    double result;


    System.out.println("A. Addition\nB. Subtraction\nC. Multiplication\nD. Division \n\nE. Exit");

    //System.out.println("\nPlease enter your selection, enter E to end:");
    //selection = input.next().charAt(0);
    //choice = Character.toUpperCase(selection);

    while(choice != 'E')
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your selection, enter E to end:");
    selection = input.next().charAt(0);
    choice = Character.toUpperCase(selection);

    if(choice == 'A') {
        System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
        num_1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
        num_2 = input.nextDouble();

        result = num_1 + num_2;
        System.out.println(result);

    }
    if(choice == 'B'){
        System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
        num_1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
        num_2 = input.nextDouble();

        result = num_1 - num_2;
        System.out.println(result);

    }
    if(choice == 'C'){
        System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
        num_1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
        num_2 = input.nextDouble();

        result = num_1 * num_2;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    if(choice == 'D'){
        System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
        num_1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
        num_2 = input.nextDouble();

        result = num_1 / num_2;
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you, have a nice day!");
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the brackets? Or is there something I'm missing for the loop to work? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `while(choice != 'E')` missing an `{` ?

Comment: "char choice = 'E';" in combination with "while(choice != 'E')" will never enter the loop and curlies are missing after the while.

Comment: I just added the curly braces, however now the program always closes right away, displaying my exit message. What should I set my choice variable to? I tried 0, but then it goes on a crazy loop forever

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
Problem is (as far as I can see) that you have nothing/only the print line in your while loop.

```
while(true) {
    do things
}
```

Java allows while loops without brackets, but at maximum one line (and I recommend doing them for one line too, but that is debattable), as soon as you need several lines, you need brackets and should have according indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your intended `while` loop with brackets to make it work the way you want:

```
while (choice != 'E') {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your selection, enter E to end:");
    selection = input.next().charAt(0);
    choice = Character.toUpperCase(selection);

    switch (choice) {
        case 'A':
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num_1 = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num_2 = input.nextDouble();

            result = num_1 + num_2;
            System.out.println(result);
            break;

        case 'B':
            // ...
    }
}

System.out.println("Thank you, have a nice day!");
```

Currently, your `while` loop will spin forever (I think), because the seed value for `choice` is being set to `E`.

Side note: Consider using a `switch` statement to handle the various case values for the choice.

Answer (score 0):

You class has two problems.

- One is the missing brace that others metioned.
- The other is that it will never enter the loop as the condition is allways false.

So to make sure that the loop is entered at least once you need an endcondition. a do-while construct instead of your startcondition.

So I changed your while loop into a do-while. By that I added the missing curly.

I also changed your if's to a switch as a choice calls for it.

And I moved the question into the loop, so the user gets the information in every iteration.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator_Loop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char selection;
        char choice = 'E';
        double num_1;
        double num_2;
        double result;


        do {
            System.out.println("A. Addition\nB. Subtraction\nC. Multiplication\nD. Division \n\nE. Exit");

            //System.out.println("\nPlease enter your selection, enter E to end:");
            //selection = input.next().charAt(0);
            //choice = Character.toUpperCase(selection);
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter your selection, enter E to end:");
            selection = input.next().charAt(0);
            choice = Character.toUpperCase(selection);
            switch (choice) {
                case 'A':
                    System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                    num_1 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                    num_2 = input.nextDouble();
                    result = num_1 + num_2;
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                    num_1 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                    num_2 = input.nextDouble();
                    result = num_1 - num_2;
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                    num_1 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                    num_2 = input.nextDouble();

                    result = num_1 * num_2;
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                    num_1 = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                    num_2 = input.nextDouble();

                    result = num_1 / num_2;
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
            }
        } while (choice != 'E');
        System.out.println("Thank you, have a nice day!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the if conditions, please use the while loop and switch condition. if the input value is other than the A, B, C or D then exit from the code.

Code takes only the first character of your input and enters into switch case, where it will compare the input with the required conditions.

```
public class Calculator_Loop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "";
        double num_1;
        double num_2;
        double result;

        System.out.println("A. Addition\nB. Subtraction\nC. Multiplication\nD. Division \n\nE. Exit");

        /*System.out.println("\nPlease enter your selection, enter E to end:");
        selection = input.next().charAt(0);
        choice = input.next().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();*/

        outer: while (true) {
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter your selection, enter E to end:");
            choice = input.next();
            choice = choice.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            switch (choice) {
            case "A":
                System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                num_1 = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                num_2 = input.nextDouble();

                result = num_1 + num_2;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;

            case "B":
                System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                num_1 = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                num_2 = input.nextDouble();

                result = num_1 - num_2;
                System.out.println(result);

                break;

            case "C":
                System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                num_1 = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                num_2 = input.nextDouble();

                result = num_1 * num_2;
                System.out.println(result);

                break;

            case "D":
                System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                num_1 = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                num_2 = input.nextDouble();

                result = num_1 / num_2;
                System.out.println(result);

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Thank you, have a nice day!");
                break outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```